# Delphi XE6 - Firemonkey applications rendering bug

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe6

I'm experimenting Firemonkey HD with Embarcadero Delphi XE6.
This is what happen when creating a form:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdfFi.png
[image]

After going over the button or resizing the window.
Also the angles are black.

I'm on Windows 7 64bits.
What's the problem?

Comment: When you say "What's the problem", what is the problem you are asking for help with?

Comment: Well, I don't know why angles and background become suddenly black when resizing or passing over the button.

Comment: Have you any event handlers coded? Has a style been set, or is one being loaded? What is the Form.Fill property set to?

Comment: We cannot see your code. I also have no idea what you mean by "angles". Please make it easy for us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Just create a new Firemonkey HD application in Delphi, add a button and that's it. No events, everything default.

Comment: I removed the delphi-xe tage, please don't add tags at random

Comment: Anyway, it works fine here. Perhaps an issue with your graphics card/driver. Try your program on some different machines to see what I mean.

Comment: I'll try in another PC and let you know.

Comment: Ok @DavidHeffernan It's a GPU problem. If run with Intel HD3000 it's fine, if run with GT540M (latest driver) there is the problem.
Same as here: https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=105437